# Can we have a string field instead of a string property in an entity class for EF Core?

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0

In an entity class for EF Core, can we have string fields:

```
public class Customer 
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}
```

instead of string properties as shown below?

```
public class Customer 
{
    public string FirstName {get; set; }
    public string LastName {get; set; }
}
```

Does it have to be a property? If so, what is the reason?

Comment: Take a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: it has to be a property with a setter and getter, otherwise it won't be assignable. you can override EF models properties, as they're `virtual` and the class is `partial` so you can create a partial class for it and customize the properties as you want.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it has to be a property for EF to consider it (unless its a backing field) @TanvirArjel